# How can I send e-mail only once in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the following problem, I have a flow that uses the Mergerecord processor at some point, generally I have about 5,000 records at the input and I need to merge them. Generally, it works ok, but sometimes somewhere along the way one or two records fall out and I get an error when merging that it cannot be merge because the quantity is not correct. This is also ok, but in such a situation I would like to receive an e-mail with information about the error in the merg. How can I make this e-mail come only once and not as many times as I have records in my flow? I've been struggling with this for the second day now and for now I receive an e-mail notification as many times as I have records that have not been merged.Maybe someone know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to re-merge records routed to `failure` using `Correlation Attribute Name` property, choose `Correlation Attribute Name` value accordingly so that you will get a single merge flowfile by merging failed records.